# Laravel attribute not working as expected

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

In the current application, there is a model `Part` and a model `Supplier`. Every Part has a Supplier.

```
    public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class);
    }
```

I added an accessor to get the name of the supplier.

If i return the whole dataset, i get the supplier:

```
    public function getSupplierNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->supplier;
    }
```

```
    "supplierName": {
        "id": 1,
        "uuid": "37e3a715-09d3-4fac-ae88-8f12e63fe79c",
        "name": "Laserteam",
        "street": "8602 Dessie Tunnel",
        "zip": "15869",
        "city": "New Clementview",
        "email_send_type": null,
        "active": 0,
        "created_at": "2020-01-09 09:46:02",
        "updated_at": "2020-01-09 09:46:02",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "action": "",
        "activeLabel": "<span class='badge badge-secondary'>Inaktiv<\/span>"
    },
```

If i try to get only the name (what I need finally), there is an error:

```
    public function getSupplierNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->supplier->name;
    }
```

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in file /gopanel/sites/7industry_net/public/7time/app/Models/Part/PartAttribute.php on line 48
```

If i try in this way, it works:

```
    public function getSupplierNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->supplier['name'];
    }
```

Why does `return $this->supplier->name;` not work?

Comment: just an idea , but try it with adding also the  foreignKey on the relationship function. : return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class,'foreignKey');

Comment: Looks like it should work. Are you sure you don't have a `toArray` anywhere? Or that you used to have it somewhere and haven't reloaded tinker yet (if you're working in tinker)?

Comment: seems silly but try `$g = $this->supplier;` then `return $g->name` if that fails `dd($g);` before the return and see what is in side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code

```
public function getSupplierNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->supplier->name ?? 'supplier not exists';
}
```

Comment: I had one `Part` without `supplier_id`. So the code works but I has to ask first, if a supplier relation exists.

Comment: @Peter But how it solves your question? You wrote in question that for every record you have supplier, so it doesn't help I believe. It only hides problem but doesn't solve it.

Comment: It was my mistake that i believed that every part has a supplier. That was the basic error!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what could be the problem here, but:

1. Make sure you don't have `supplier` in casts for your model
2. Make sure you don't use `supplier` for database column name or you don't make somewhere something this

   ```
   $this->supplier = $this->supplier->toArray();
   ```

It seems `supplier` property somewhere becomes array that's why one notation works but the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not really sure what’s going on there; if you have a `supplier` relation then accessing the property *should* lazy-load the relationship.

Alternatively, you could try this syntax:

```php
public function getSupplierNameAttribute()
{
    $this->loadMissing('supplier');

    return $this->getRelation('supplier')->name;
}
```

**However**, I’d avoid defining accessors like this. It can lead to N+1 problems if you say, retrieve a collection of parts and then call `$part->supplier_name` on each one without eager-loading the `supplier` relationship.

Personally, if I’m accessing attributing on relations that I prefer to do it through the relation (i.e. `$part->supplier->name`) so any relations I need to eager load are shown to me.

Comment: I use the datatable from webix. Therefore i need the supplierName on the first level. Perhaps i will do it later with a api resource.